# How to bundle React component as NPM package that is ready for server side rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, server-side-rendering

I created a React component and published it as package on NPM. It works as planed on client side, however, when I try to do ssr with next.js it crashes with error `ReferenceError: document is not defined`. Through simple search I found that my bundle and my component depends on existence of `document`. It is important to note my package does not use react-dom.

How do I bundle the component/s with webpack so the package can be imported and used in ssr applications?

I tried changing the target and libraryTarget, but I was not able to achieve what I needed. Also, through research I found that often people write two different code in their packages for client side and server side rendering. However, I could not find how to write react component for ssr and how it could exclude document from it. If it is true that one needs to write React component specifically for server, then how can it be done?

Bellow I am sending my webpack configuration.

Webpack

````
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

const web = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$|.tsx$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'commonjs react',
    'react-apollo': 'commonjs react-apollo',
    graphql: 'commonjs graphql',
    'graphql-tag': 'commonjs graphql-tag',
  },
}

const node = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.node.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$|.tsx$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: [
    nodeExternals(),
    {
      react: 'commonjs react',
      'react-apollo': 'commonjs react-apollo',
      graphql: 'commonjs graphql',
      'graphql-tag': 'commonjs graphql-tag',
    },
  ],
}

module.exports = [web, node]```
````

Comment: If you want to use it with next.js, you can import it with `dynamic` from `next/dynamic` and give the `{ ssr: false }` option. Alternatively, wrap your code which uses document in a useEffect(()=>{if(typeof document != 'undefined'){/*code*/}}, [])

Comment: @George Thank you. I tried that and it worked. It wasn't what I was hoping for but it does work. Also, I am confuse as I tried to cause the same error when doing the ssr with React and Express.js (first time trying ssr with Express). However, I wasn't able, everything worked out of the box. So I am not sure am I doing something wrong with Express or Next js does something differently so my component doesn't work with ssr on Next but works with Express.

Comment: @George How to create the package such that it can be used both on client side and server side